# npm is raising and error on mac, and not working in any way

Tags: node.js, npm

When i run `npm` or `npm start` and so on... It is raising the following error.

```
    npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
    npm ERR! Cannot find module 'ci-info'
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/narendra/.npm/_logs/2018-09-21T11_19_20_365Z- debug.log
```

I'am not able to understand what that 'ci-info' is and even not able to search for that module in npm, because of the same error, which is not letting me use the npm.

Can anyone help me with this.

note: `npm --version` is working.

Comment: ci-info is available in npm. You need to install Ci-info to fix the error do this npm install ci-info --save and then npm start

Comment: @HemadriDasari Any npm command throws this error. Including `npm install`. How do we install without the install command?